# Difference of square roots of positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, radicals, positive-semidefinite

Let $Y$ and $X$ be positive semidefinite matrices of size $d \times d$. We define $\sqrt{Y}$ and $\sqrt{X}$ as the unique symmetric positive semidefinite matrices that satisfy $(\sqrt{Y})^2 = Y$ and $(\sqrt{X})^2 = X$. I need to show that there exists a constant $C>0$ (that may depend on $d$) such that
$$|| \sqrt{X}-\sqrt{Y}||^2 \leq C ||X-Y||.  $$ The norm is defined as $||A|| = \sqrt{Trace(AA^*)}.$

Here's what I first did:
By considering the eigendecomposition $Y = H \Lambda H^*$, we have $\sqrt{Y} = H \sqrt{\Lambda} H^*$ and
$$|| \sqrt{X}-\sqrt{Y}||^2 = Trace(( H \sqrt{\Lambda} H^* - \sqrt{X})(H \sqrt{\Lambda} H^* - \sqrt{X})^* ) 
 = Trace(H ( \sqrt{\Lambda}  - H^*\sqrt{X} H )(\sqrt{\Lambda}  - H^*\sqrt{X} H)^* H^*) = Trace(( \sqrt{\Lambda}  - H^*\sqrt{X} H )(\sqrt{\Lambda}  - H^*\sqrt{X} H)^*) $$ since $H H^* = I_d.$ In other words, we can assume that $Y$ is diagonal, without loss of generality. Note that  $H^*\sqrt{X} H$ is also positive semidefinite.

Then:
$$ Trace(( \sqrt{Y}  - \sqrt{X} )(\sqrt{Y}  - \sqrt{X})^*) 
 = Trace( Y - X + 2 X -\sqrt{X} \sqrt{Y} - \sqrt{Y} \sqrt{X} )$$
$$ Trace( Y - X ) + 2 Trace( X -\sqrt{X} \sqrt{Y} ) = Trace( Y - X ) + 2 Trace( \sqrt{X} ( \sqrt{X} -  \sqrt{Y}) ) $$ 
$$ \leq ||Y-X|| + 2 Trace( \sqrt{X} ( \sqrt{X} -  \sqrt{Y}) ) $$

Then what?

Comment: Apply the definition here then elevate both sides square when it is as Trace...

Comment: What happens with the trace of the left side when it is squared ?

Comment: First left side is a sum of traces then square the sum of Traces.  (an idea)